# How to vertically scale google cloud instance without stopping running app

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, autoscaling

I have a Node.js app that provides a service which cannot be interrupted.

However the load to the app varies overtime and to save cost I would like the vm instance machine type to autoscale in function of the load (ie when over 80% CPU utilisation, scale up from 1 vCPU(3.75 GB memory, n1-standard-1) to 2vCPU(7.5 GB memory, n1-standard-2))

Is this possible?

PS: I have looked at using the container engine and kubernetes but due to how the app operates, the app cannot be replicated to multiple pods and continue working

Comment: You can instantiate the new vm and run the app on that (without killing the old vm), then route all traffic to the new vm, and then finally kill the old vm. Since you say "app cannot be replicated to multiple pods", not sure if this setup is possible for you. Is it?

Comment: This setup isn't really possible for me but I will probably have to change my app to work like this. Thanks for the help @NikhilJindal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only change the machine type of a stopped instance and an instance is considered stopped only when the instance is in the TERMINATED state. It is not possible to change the machine type of a running instance.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance